# Why is my unit test for Kafka in Python not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, apache-kafka, python-unittest

```py
from kafka import KafkaProducer, errors, admin, KafkaConsumer


SERVERS = ['localhost:9092']
TEST_TOPIC = 'test-topic'

DATA = [{'A':'A'}, {'A':'A'}, {'A':'A'}]

class TestKafkaConsumer(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        self._producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=SERVERS, value_serializer=lambda x:dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

    def _send_data(self):
        for data in DATA:
            print(self._producer.send(TEST_TOPIC, value=data))

    def test_basic_processing(self):
        self._send_data()
        received = []
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(TEST_TOPIC, bootstrap_servers=SERVERS)

        for msg in consumer:
            message = json.loads(msg.value.decode('utf-8'))
            received.append(message)
            if (len(received) >= len(DATA)):
                self.assertEqual(received, DATA)
```

This should succeed pretty quickly, as it just sends the data to the the Kafka broker in a pretty straightforward manner. However, it times out; the consumer never reads a single message. If I move the consumer portion to a different file and run it in a different terminal window, the messages are "consumed" pretty instantly. Why is the unittest not working for a consumer in this unittest?

Comment: Did you every find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're producing records with your producer and then you're reading, this might be your problem.
When your consumer is started, you already had produced records, so, from the consumer point of view, there are no new messages.
You should run your consumer in a different thread, before your producer start producing.

Yannick